# How to remove the automatic ratings from songs in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ratings

I want to remove the automatic ratings from my songs:

[image]

However, they don't disappear after <kbd>right-click</kbd><sup><sub>-></sub></sup>**Rating**<sup><sub>-></sub></sup>**None**

Answer (score 18):

That is because the songs inherit an "estimate rating" from the album rating. If you want to remove these stars, you need to remove the album rating.

Click on the left of the stars from the album the song belongs:

[image]

they are now gone:

[image]

Apparently, this is the only way to change the album rating (the right-click menu doesn't show any options to change the rating).

Comment: this is not working (or no longer working) in iTunes 12.5.4 on Windows :(

Comment: When I do this (Mac iTunes 12.7.0.166), the rating just immediately regenerates itself based on the current average of all songs in the album.  There appears to be no way to actually remove an album rating.  This is particularly frustrating with the "Unknown Album" album by "Unknown Artist", which in my library has a lot of tracks in it, some rated but most not.  There is no album here, so it should have no rating.

Answer (score 3):

I have a smart playlist that displays songs with "No Rating" in order to listen to, rate them, and put them in the applicable playlists I have. My problem was that the Auto Rating for an album would give all other songs on the album (that the song I just rated was part of) a grayed out rating. Then when the Smart Playlist updated it would delete the grayed out songs from my playlist and I would have unrated songs floating around.

To combat this I enabled half-star ratings for my iTunes. http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Enable-Half-Stars-In-Itunes/

I was using 1 star to denote a song to be deleted. (Wayyyy to much music in my itunes) But I changed that system to use a 1/2 star rating to denote deletion.

This is because the best way to keep songs from being removed from my "Unrated" smart playlist was to do this.

Go to music, playlist view.
Sort songs by rating.
Go to the first song that has no rating.
Click it (It should be highlighted blue)
Now, scroll alllll the way down to the last song.
HOLD SHIFT and click that last song.
Now all of the No Rating songs are highlighted.
Right click,
Rating, 1 star.

I then updated the smart playlist to show songs with a 1 star rating.
Now, rating one song in an album will not change the ratings of the others in the same album and my Smart Playlist functions as intended.

I'm currently 22% of my way through rating and sorting my 14220 songs. This 'fix' will save me a lot of time of having to go write down all the albums that iTunes automatically rated, then go to album view and one by one unrate the albums.

If you would like a somewhat easier way to unrate albums. Right click on the bar where "artists" "songs" "time" "rating" is and add the "Album Rating" to the bar.
Now sort using that button and just look for the darkened star ratings. click 1 song in that album to highlight it. Then click and hold in the Album Rating for that song and drag to the left to give it "No Rating".

TL:DR  I finally found a way to keep iTunes from pissing me off and wasting hours of my time.

Answer (score 1):

I FIGURED IT OUT!

When you add a column view called 'Album Rating', it adds an Album Rating item in your right click menu also called Album Rating directly below Song Rating.  Return to Album View, right click on the album cover and select NONE in Album Rating and it clears it....

Comment: Don’t do this! If you try this, it also deletes the rating of every individual song in the album, and the Undo menu item doesn’t let you get those ratings back.